# PHP return JS UTC date format

Tags: php, javascript, date, utc

Is there any way I can return a date using PHP that is the same format that Date.UTC(y,m,d) returns?

Here is an example of the format I need:

1274745600000 (Apr 25, 2010)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP:

```
$date = '13-09-2010 00:00:00';
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
echo  (strtotime($date) * 1000) - (strtotime('02-01-1970 00:00:00') * 1000);
//1286928000000
```

Javascript:

```
Date.UTC(2010, 9, 13);
//1286928000000
```

Comment: is there any idea how to get it froom Carbon package?

Answer (score 2):

**[EDITed]:**

The way it returns **OUTPUT** is the milliseconds from January 1, 1970 to July 8, 2005, according to universal time: which you can get by [`mktime`](http://php.net/mktime) and appending three `0` like this:

```
echo mktime(0, 0, 0, 9, 15, 2010).'000';
```

This will display:

> 1284508800000

---

And you can use date function to get in JS UTC **INPUT** format:

```
echo date("Y,n,j");
```

This will display:

> 2010,9,15

---

Comment: The UTC() method returns the number of milliseconds in a date string since midnight of January 1, 1970, according to universal time.

Comment: I'm trying to return a date in JS UTC format directly from PHP so I don't have to convert it using JS. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, using `mktime` (the first method), it is possible. It returns the data in UTC format. Try it.

Comment: @shamittormar mktime() returns SECONDS. Date.UTC() returns milliseconds in a slightly different format.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your function use

`date_default_timezone_set('UTC');`

This set the default timezone to use. Available since PHP 5.1.And you can simply **echo date** by **date()** function.